# switch fuera de ciclo for en angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un arreglo en el cual cada item tiene un estado, para ello lo que hago es buscar los estados GENERADOS o PENDIENTES y dependiendo de cada busqueda se asigna un numero a la variable valor para luego ser utilizada en un switch y dependiendo de ese valor hacer ciertas operaciones.

A continuación muestro mi código:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

    //myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
    //myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

    function MyCtrl($scope) {
        $scope.name = [
            {"id":1, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":2, "estado":"PENDIENTE"},
          {"id":3, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":4, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":5, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":6, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":7, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":8, "estado":"PENDIENTE"},
          {"id":9, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
          {"id":10, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"}
        ];
        var valor = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.name, function(item){
            if(item.estado === 'GENERADO'){
            valor = 1;               
          }else{
            if(item.estado === 'PENDIENTE'){
              valor = 2;
            }else{
              valor = 3; 
            }                                             
          }
        })
        switch(valor){
            case 1:
            console.log(valor);
            //hacer operaciones correspondientes
          break;
          case 2:
             console.log(valor)
           //hacer operaciones correspondientes
          break;
          case 3:
            console.log(valor+' no hay nada que hacer')
          break;
          default:
          return false; 
        }
    }
```

Pero mi error es que siempre obtiene el último valor. Como puedo resolver este problema?.... la idea es que deseo hacerlo fuera del ciclo For

de antemano les agradezco....!

Comment: Pero no comprendo por que prefieres hacerlo fuera del For ¿qué motivo define esa restricción?

Answer (score 2):

Pienso que la variable valor debe ir dentro del for, y el Switch también, sino no tiene sentido que quieras ejecutar el Switch 1 sola vez, fuera del for, y al mismo tiempo te disguste el que quede con el último valor. Es entonces sobre el tema que dices que quieres hacerlo fuera del for lo que no comprendo

Puedes emplear una función, como dice el amigo, si deseas aligerar la lógica del for, o si quieres dejar esa lógica aparte (desacoplar el switch); no obstante, la única forma en que le veo sentido es que hayas intentado asignar la variable 'valor' y no te imprimió lo que esperabas dentro del for, y eso se debe a que la variable está declara antes del for, y la asignación, está en el ámbito del for, lo que provoca que en toda las iteraciones pudiera imprimirte siempre el mismo último valor.

Para ello debes cambiar la declaración de valor, y reubicarla en el for, eso hará que la variable se sobre escriba o re-declare, en cada iteración (no tengo del todo claro por que funciona así, pero funciona en varios lenguajes y tiene que ver con el ámbito de declaración), y si quieres luego accederla en el ámbito posterior al for, ahi empleas una variable similar a la que tienes ahora

El detalle, sútil, pero casi que un truco, es que debes usar "var valor = ..." dentro del for

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = [
        {"id":1, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":2, "estado":"PENDIENTE"},
      {"id":3, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":4, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":5, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":6, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":7, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":8, "estado":"PENDIENTE"},
      {"id":9, "estado":"NO_AUTORIZADO"},
      {"id":10, "estado":"AUTORIZADO"}
    ];
    //var valor = 0;//Ya no iría aquí
    angular.forEach($scope.name, function(item){
      var valor = 0;//pero aquí si funciona, debe tener var para que sea una instancia diferente en cada iteración

      if(item.estado === 'GENERADO'){
        valor = 1;               
      }else{
        if(item.estado === 'PENDIENTE'){
          valor = 2;
        }else{
          valor = 3; 
        }                                             
      }

        console.log(valor); // este varía para cada iteración
        procesarItem(valor);
        //si prefieres aquí llamas a una función que tenga el switch
    });

   function procesarItem(valor) {

    switch(valor){
        case 1:
        console.log(valor);
        //hacer operaciones correspondientes
      break;
      case 2:
         console.log(valor)
       //hacer operaciones correspondientes
      break;
      case 3:
        console.log(valor+' no hay nada que hacer')
      break;
      default:
      return false; 
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

aplicando conocimientos de javascript y no asi directamente angularjs

> Podria crear una funcion que tenga de parametro callback, y mediante
>   ello obtener el resultado valor para poder trabajarlo.

```js
function prueba(retorno){
angular.forEach($scope.name, function(item){
            if(item.estado === 'GENERADO'){
            valor = 1;               
          }else{
            if(item.estado === 'PENDIENTE'){
              valor = 2;
            }else{
              valor = 3; 
            }                                             
          }
return retorno(null,valor);
        })


}

prueba(function(err, valor){
  switch(valor){
            case 1:
            console.log(valor);
            //hacer operaciones correspondientes
          break;
          case 2:
             console.log(valor)
           //hacer operaciones correspondientes
          break;
          case 3:
            console.log(valor+' no hay nada que hacer')
          break;
          default:
          return false; 
        }
})
```

Comment: no sale amigo, da el mismo problema que tengo, me muestra el ultimo valor

Comment: @DiegoIsraelMoreno he editato mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

La razón es que solo hay una variable valor, en cada iteración esa variable cambia de valor, y dado que la última iteración no es ni pendiente ni generado, entonces siempre valdrá 3, si lo que quieres es hacerlo fuera del for puedes declarar valor como un arreglo, `var valor = []` y luego ir insertando cada valor en el.

```
angular.forEach($scope.name, function(item){
        if(item.estado === 'GENERADO'){
        valor.push(1);               
      }else{
        if(item.estado === 'PENDIENTE'){
          valor.push(2);
        }else{
          valor.push(3); 
        }                                             
      }
    })
```

o incluso agregarselos a tu arreglo original

```
angular.forEach($scope.name, function(item){
        if(item.estado === 'GENERADO'){
        item.valor = 1;               
      }else{
        if(item.estado === 'PENDIENTE'){
          item.valor = 2;
        }else{
          item.valor = 3; 
        }                                             
      }
    })
```

y despues imprimirlos con algún ciclo